# Javascript bug? Code with same logic gives different results

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.getElementById("volslider").value -= -step; //WORKS as intended
document.getElementById("volslider").value += step; //Takes slider to 50/100 for any step value
```

```html
<input type="range" id="volslider" min="0" max="100" value="100" oninput="updateVolume(this.value)"/>
```

The above code produces different results although it shouldn't. Does anyone know why?

Comment: `value` is always a **string**. `+` is defined for both strings and numbers, but `-` isn't, so `-` does implicit conversion to number where `+` does not.

Comment: Note that you can use `valueAsNumber` on modern browsers, see [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).